# SVG in Vuejs vfor loop for categories from WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, api

I've been trying to add svg's from a sprite.svg file into a loop that get the categories from the wordpress rest api but I'm stuggling to find a way of adding them using the category name where I stated "INSERT-HERE". In the sprite.svg they correspond with the category name. This is one of my first projects that Im doing so any help would be appreciated.

```js
<template>
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="container grid grid-cols-5 text-default pt-1">
            <div v-for="category in filteredCat" :key="category.id" @click="toCategoryPage(category.name, category.id)" class="group transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out hover:-mt-1 cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 mr-4">
                <router-link :to="{path: `/blog/${category.name}`}" active-class="active" class="flex items-center" exact>
                    <svg :class="`group-hover:fill-${category.id}`" class="w-1/5 h-12 pr-3 fill-default">
                        <use href="../assets/svg/sprite.svg#INSERT-HERE"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <h3 :class="`group-hover:text-${category.id}`" class="text-xl font-semibold">{{ category.name }}</h3>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shadow-md h-1"></div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<use :href=`../assets/svg/sprite.svg#${category.name}`></use>
```

Or this:

```
<use :href="'../assets/svg/sprite.svg#' + category.name + '"></use>
```